# Selecting values from two columns and concatenating them into a column on the same table within two date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to concatenate two columns into one, on the same table. But I need to do this for records that were added within a specific time period. I am thinking of doing something like:

```sql
BEGIN TRAN
    UPDATE dbo.TableName SET NewColumn = CONCAT(ISNULL(column1, ''), ' ', ISNULL(column2, ''))
COMMIT
```

I am running the query on MSSQL. I am not sure how to add the date constraint

Comment: Just an aside:  Your isnull() would not be necessary within the concat().   concat treats null values as an empty string.

Comment: The `' '` might also want to be a concatenated to the `column1` using the concatenation operator (`+`) too, rather than within `CONCAT`. Otherwise for rows where `column1` does have the value `NULL` your column `NewColumn` would have a leading space, which is unlikely desired. Or, perhaps, you should be using `CONCAT_WS`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a `WHERE` clause with the `BETWEEN` keyword, like

```
WHERE column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2;
```

Now, instead of `column_name` you will need to use your date column and instead of `value1` and `value2`, respectively, you will need to use your date boundaries.